# TeamProjectPicker is defaulting to an incorrect TFS instance

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I am creating a small application that utilizes the TeamProjectPicker. In my work setting, I currently have two TFS instances as items are being migrated to 2015. I am trying to write against the 2015 instance and its items, but when I run the application the TeamProjectPicker is defaulting to our older 2010 instance. The two instances:

xxx.xxx.60.85/tfs (2010 instance - my application is defaulting to this)
xxx.xxx.40.175/tfs (2015 instance)

Is there a way I can get the Picker to change to the correct TFS instance? Below is the code I have for the Picker:

```
using (tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, true))
        {
            DialogResult result = tpp.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the `TeamProjectPicker`. You can modify the behavior by providing a new `ITeamProjectPickerDefaultSelectionProvider`.

For details, see the blog post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/04/20/using-the-teamprojectpicker-api-in-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: Sorry got delayed on this project but this appears to be working. Thank you for the assist!